# ROS TimeSynchronizer callback with different thread ids

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, ros

I'm debugging a Python ROS node that subscribes to two messages and uses a `TimeSynchronizer` to call a single function.

```
self.image_sub = message_filters.Subscriber("/camera/color/image_raw", Image)
self.depth_sub = message_filters.Subscriber("/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw", Image)

self.ts = message_filters.TimeSynchronizer([self.image_sub, self.depth_sub], 1)       
self.ts.registerCallback(self.callback)
```

In the callback function I'm rendering some data using the Open3D library. From time to time I get this message printed in the terminal `GLFW Error: GLX: Failed to make context current` and the rendering is just black. I suspected it maybe a problem of using the Open3D library from different threads. So I printed the current thread ID from inside the callback function:

```
def callback(self, rgb_data, depth_data):
    import threading
    print("thread:", threading.current_thread())        

    try:
        self.color_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(rgb_data, "bgr8")
        self.depth_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(depth_data, "16UC1")
    except CvBridgeError as e:
        print(e)        

    #Do some rendering involving self.color_image, self.depth_image
    #...

    return
```

Most of the time I get this print out:

```
('thread:', <Thread(/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw, started daemon 140521947203328)>)
```

But then I occasionally get this another one:

```
('thread:', <Thread(/camera/color/image_raw, started daemon 140521476069120)>)
```

When this happens I get the `GLFW Error: GLX: Failed to make context current` message. It seems Open3D can't be used from a different thread to the one that initialized its context.

But my question is, why is the callback called from two possible threads? and can I configure `TimeSynchronizer` or something else so that my callback gets always called from the same thread?

---

[**NOTE**]:

- I'm in Ubuntu 16.04 and using ROS Kinetic.
- For the moment I've avoided the problem by queuing into a deque my two images in the callback, and have the main thread to process the deque. That seems to solve the problem. However, I have to deal with things that ROS provides already through the messaging system. Also, I'm still curious as to why despite there is a single callback it can be called from different threads, it seems like a bug to me.

Comment: So your registered callback is only suited for `self.depth_sub`?

Comment: The registered callback works well for both self.image_sub and self.depth_sub. The problem is that, surprisingly, it's called from different threads and that gives me problems with the graphics rendering.

Comment: How do you know it works well for `self.depth_sub` when it fails as soon as the thread which runs it executes the callback? I didn't know of `ROS` before but after taking a quick look at the [docs](http://docs.ros.org/api/message_filters/html/python/#message_filters.Subscriber) the behaviour you observe to me seems like what you should expect. You are registering the callback on `TimeSynchronizer`, which channels multiple threads. You generally cannot predict the order threads will finish, so it's random which thread will execute your callback.

Comment: From my understanding registering callbacks on `TimeSynchronizer` is meant for callbacks with general tasks where it doesn't matter
which thread is active. If you want to register a callback for a specific thread you should be able to do so with registering it directly on the single `Subscriber`, in your case `self.depth_sub.registerCallback(self.callback)`.

Comment: @Darkonaut I've added the callback function to my question. From the signature of the function you wouldn't expect that sometimes it'd be called from one thread and sometimes from another. I would expect it always to be called from the same thread, a TimeSynchronizer specific thread.

Comment: Apparently there is no `TimeSynchronizer` thread executing your callback how your prints show. `TimeSynchronizer` internally seems to utilize a queue. You have specified `queue_size` with `1` although you have two Subscribers. I think this leads your callback to get triggered as soons as one Subscriber has a message. I would try setting `queue_size=2`.

Comment: queue_size=2 seems to affect the behaviour. It worked well with a prerecorded sequence but with live video I still get the GLFW Error. if I set queue_size=20 it seems to work well until the queue is full, then I'll get the GLFW Error. So it seems that whatever the queue_size, If I don't lose frames the callback is always from the same thread, but if I lose frames (because I don't process them fast enough) the next callback may come from a different thread.

Comment: "It seems Open3D can't be used from a different thread to the one that initialized its context."  I have no Open3D experience but I just recalled this is a similar behaviour to `OpenCV` where you can't use multiple threads for displaying windows since `Qt` makes the first thread it's `MainThread` where the windowing framework runs in. You can use `OpenCV` functions to calculate frames in different threads  but you need to centralize the display.